# On Amazon Mechanical Turk (MTurk), do I need to pay extra to extend a batch of HITs?

Tags: amazon

I have a batch of HITs on Amazon Mturk that aren't quite done yet. They're about to expire and I want to extend the time (not the number of HITs) so that the batch can finish.

However, when I click the "Extend this batch" button, Amazon gives me this error message:

*Your account does not have sufficient funds to extend these HITs. Click [here](https://requester.mturk.com/prepayments/new) to fund your account.*

I was under the impression that the cost was based on the number of assignments and not the length of time. Is that not the case? Can I not extend the batch for free?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is due to [a really old quirk/bug](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=90655) in Amazon's system.

Extending the batch won't cost any extra money, but in order to do so, your account must have a balance that's greater than or equal to the total cost of the batch.

After you've added the money to your account and extended the batch, you can request a refund to get the account balance back.

Alternatively, if you plan to use MTurk in the future, you can leave the account balance there and use it to pay for your future orders.